# Prove: $o(ab)=o(ba)$

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group prove that $o(ab)=o(ba)$

I have started with let $(ab)^n=e$ now because $G$ is a group there is $(ab)^{-1}\in G$ but can I conclude it is $b^{-1}a^{-1}$?

Comment: Well, what is $a b b^{-1} a^{-1}=$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Observe that $(ba)^{n+1}=b(ab)^na$.

Hence, if $(ab)^n=e$, then $(ba)^{n+1}=ba$, and therefore $(ba)^n=e$.

Now its your turn to produce a clean proof !

Comment: why $(ba)^{n+1}=b(ab)^na$?

Comment: @gbox For $n = 1$ you have e.g. $(ba)^2 = (ba)(ba) = b(ab)a$

Comment: @Dominik using associativity?

Comment: @gbox Yes $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @ gbox: for $(ba)^{n+1}=b(ab)^na$ use an easy induction argument !

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, in any group $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$, just because
\begin{align*}
  (ab)^{-1} &= (ab)^{-1}aa^{-1}\\
            &= (ab)^{-1}abb^{-1}a^{-1}\\
            &= b^{-1}a^{-1}
\end{align*}